# Deployment process using Django 1.3, South and Fabric for Custom SQL operations

Tags: python, django, django-south

We are currently using django 1.3 throuh Fabric we are able to push code to staging and production and maintain the changes on the database level through South.

At the time, we are faced with set of SQL maintaince statement that we need to push as part of a certain deployment. Most these SQL operations are not specific for South nor can be captured by South, such as table analyzing, dropping some old tables..etc.

Can you please advise on how can we batch such activity using the same deployment process?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since south can run any Python code why not to use direct SQL there?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: This can definitely work for me, but how would i place this to run as part of south migrations?

Comment: `python manage.py datamigration app_name migration_name` won't work?